# Accepting a new job offer shortly after starting a job

Tags: new-job

So I am a graduate, nothing's confirmed yet, but I want to prepare for this hypothetical situation just in case. I'm currently desperate for a job, so I applied for not only jobs in the industry I want to work for (I.T.) but I applied for other jobs such as retail stores. I have an interview this week with a local supermarket for a part-time job, which is great. However this morning a friend of mine, who does the exact job I want to do, just told me that his company is hiring for a graduate role, and he said if I apply he'll put in a good word for me to his manager.

So this is the hypothetical part, what if I get this supermarket part time job, then a couple of weeks later I get an interview and then get offered a job for the IT job. Out of the 2 jobs I obviously want the IT job, but is it acceptable to leave a job so soon after leaving?

Comment: VTC duplicate. This has been asked and answered dozens of times before. The part-time retail angle might change things but not sufficiently to merit a distinct question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the contract you have signed with the supermarket. There should be either a probation period during which they can fire you or you can leave, pretty much anytime. Then there's a notice period where you have to tell your boss in advance that you want to leave. It's pretty much normal to interview for a new job while being hired, and announcing your notice period to your new boss so they can plan for your arrival.

And don't worry about not staying on a supermarket job for long: no one will hold this against you (I wouldn't even put it on the CV). It may become a problem if you keep hopping jobs afterwards, without having a good reason to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I haven't had an interview yet so I may not even get the supermaket job, I just wanted to prepare just in case.

Comment: Agreed.  In these circumstances the supermarket will be expecting you to only be around a relatively short time before leaving for greener pa$ture$.